# Richardson Extrapolation Matlab Code: Example and try out code included.

Tags: matlab, extrapolation

currently I am studying Numerical Methods in Matlab and I need a Matlab code which would calculate Richardson Extrapolation using data given in a table, respectively for x and f(x).

For example: *Use the table below to calculate f'(0) as accurately as possible.*

[image]

Our professor suggested to use the find function in Matlab, as I did, but so far I only get an empty matrix as a result..

> function G = richEx(x,y,xp)
>
> h=x(2)-x(1);
>
> h2=h;
>
> h1=h2*2;
>
> g1 = (-3 * ( find(y==(xp))) + 4 * (find(y==(xp + h1))) - (find(y==(xp) + 2*h1)))) / 2*h1;
>
> g2 = (-3 * (find(y==(xp))) + 4 * (find(y==(xp + h2))) - (find(y==(xp + 2*h2)))) / 2 * h2;
>
> G=(4*g2-g1)/3;

Can someone help me? Thank you.

Comment: Note that *find* returns a vector of the indices of the numbers you want. So I'm not sure this code does what you want. Either way, since it's a vector, you should use .* instead of *.

Answer (score 1):

Your `find` method is returning empty matrices because it's looking for values of `y` equal to some condition.

For instance, `find(y == xp)` looks for values of `y` equal to `xp` and it returns the index. You haven't told us what `xp` is, but chances are, there aren't any values of `y` that equal `xp`.

Furthermore, find returns the *index* of the value. So `find([4 5 6]==4)` returns `1`.

I would re-visit the Richardson extrapolation algorithm, because your code does not reflect what the algorithm does.

Comment: I'd also add that using `==` on floating-point values is a bad idea.

Comment: Which also makes using `find` somewhat... blargh. It's doable, but it would lead to some ugly code.